# Does Boost Asio SSL Free OpenSSL Allocations?

Tags: boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

Does Boost::asio::ssl free all the allocation made by OpenSSL? I know from using OpenSSL directly, I have to call things like BIO_free_all, SSL_CTX_free, etc. Does Asio do this? If so , when does it free the allocations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source, `boost::asio::ssl` does indeed appear to free up its OpenSSL allocations. e.g. `SSL_CTX_free` is called in `context`'s destructor.

Comment: Thanks for the location, I must have skimmed over it.